# Pagination function not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, function, pagination, uri

Hi everyone can someone explain what dose this do

```
$this->uri->segment());
```

its part of my pagination function and I cant figure out why I need it and if there is something to replace it with. Its causing an error in my script. Thanx for ur help. Also im new to codeigniter and php plys try to make it simple form me tnx in advance.

error message

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: views/survay_view.php
>
> Line Number: 31

here is my all code for my pagination function

```
//pagination
        function page()
           {

            $this->load->library('pagination');


            $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/admin/index.php/survay/';
            $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('save_survay')->num_rows();

            $config['per_page'] = 1;
            $config['num_links'] =10;

            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
            //print_r($this->uri->segment());die;

            $data['records'] = $this->db->get('save_survay', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment());
            $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
            $this->load->view('survay_view', $data);

          }
    }
```

Comment: It means uri isn't a valid object, so you can't then call a member function `segment` on it. Find out why that member isn't set. You could try making the base url look normal.

Comment: where should i start looking to see which member is not set and can u expand more on how to make the base url look normal ?

Comment: The uri segment should point to the parameter in url which contains page number.

Comment: i did point to it its the first segment and the errors did not change and other suggestions? thei will be gratly greatly appreciated tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `$this->uri->segment();` means a particular URI segment.

So for example if you have a URL /page/view/1

If you did echo `$this->uri->segment(2);` it would return 'view'.

See http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html for further information.

Comment: do u have any suggestions how to fix the error i get ? i read the Codeigniter user guide link u send me i understand what it does but cat still figure out how to fix this error.

Comment: I'm not sure of your URL structure, but you need to change the line `$data['records'] = $this->db->get('save_survay', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment());` to include the correct segment, I.E. `$this->uri->segment(2)` or `$this->uri->segment(3)` depending on your URL. If you `print_r($data['records'])`, what does it display?

Comment: it displays an error 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for CI_URI::segment(), called in C:\wamp\www\admin\application\controllers\survay.php on line 43 and defined

Filename: core/URI.php

Line Number: 341

Comment: As I said - You need to use `$this->uri->segment(2)` or `$this->uri->segment(3)` NOT `$this->uri->segment()`

Answer (score 0):

this    $this->uri->segment(); is actually pick up the value from url. just like $_GET[]. 
see http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html for details help.

Comment: do u have any suggestions how to fix the error i get ? i read the Codeigniter user guide link u send me i understand what it does but cat still figure out how to fix this error.

Comment: error is coming for $this->db->get I think. because I think that function is in your controller and $this->db->get this is the property of model. for undefined object error is coming.

Comment: the tutorial that i followed used $this->db->get in the controller and it worked for him with no errors maybe it's something else if u have any more suggestions this will be greatly appreciated

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html -- help link for pagination. and http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html . check this 2 links. think it will help you.